# Extracting zip file content sequentially without loading entire zip to memory using JS

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, zip, jszip

So I have a small react web app for our contractors to upload relatively large zip files (1gb to 5gb) into our AWS s3 storage. Before uploading these zip files I would need to do some validation:

- Check the total number of files inside the zip
- Check the file naming
- Check the files size
- Check the files mine type (using file-type package)
- etc.

I'm currently using JSZip with an HTML input element and the library works well with zip files that are smaller then 2GB since the library loads the entire zip in memory as stated in the 'limitation' section of there documentation.

Is there a way in a browser to essentially stream the zip files one after another without the limitation of loading the entire zip in memory? Which will inevitably cause problem with larger zip.

Current code

```
jszip.loadAsync(file).then((zip) => {
  // Some validation on total number of files
  zip.forEach((path, file) => {
    // Some validation on file naming
    file.async("uint8array").then((buffer) => {
      // Some validation on file type & size
    })
  })
})
```